# How do i make a menu like Spotify

Tags: ios

Ok as the question suggests, I want to make a menu like the spotify app currently have.
I have come across a code in [github](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) that resembles this but i want to know how to achieve this on a DIY(Do it yourself) level.

I can understand that a pageview controller is needed but am lost. Please point me to the right direction.

## EDIT

So that people might understand properly the requirement I am talking about, Here is a png [image]

Notice the top menu that slides with the underline as the selected menu.

The github link that i posted is a library that does that, but its in swift, so can anyone tell me as to how to achieve this in objective c

Regards

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Comment: Please read the question before commenting, I dont want a slidemenu, i want a top menu like sportify does.

Comment: Just check out some pageviewcontroller tutorials.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question

Comment: I know how to implement page view controllers but the problem is maintaining the active menu and the underline. @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: I maintained that in my sample.. but it is in swift. That is a bit different from this.

Comment: need the objective one.. but then again, plz sent the link you are talking about, might help

Comment: ok let me push the code on github.. giving the link in a moment as answer

Answer (score 3):

I have made a similar kind of sample but that is in Swift 2.0. Have a look. May be it can be of some help.

In the sample link posted below, the query you are asking can be done in the following way.

We can use this method to setup the buttons first on the top of page view

In your terms this is the **Top Menu**

```
func setupSegmentButtons(){
    navigationView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! - 4))
    //navigationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    navigationView.layoutIfNeeded()
    let numControllers:NSInteger = viewControllerArray.count
    if(buttonText == nil)
    {
        buttonText = NSArray(objects: "First","Second","Third")
    }

    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width/CGFloat(numControllers)
    for (var i = 0; i < numControllers; i++) {


        let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake( CGFloat(i) * buttonWidth, 0, buttonWidth, 40))
        button.addTarget(self, action: "tapSegmentButtonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        navigationView.addSubview(button)
        button.tag = i
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle(buttonText.objectAtIndex(i) as? String, forState: .Normal)

    }

    self.view.addSubview(navigationView)
    self.setupSelector()
}
```

Now we have to add the selection bar which will slide accordingly with the menu selected.

Setting up the **selection bar** view

```
func setupSelector(){

//selection bar view
    selectionBar = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(X_BUFFER - X_OFFSET + SELECTED_POSITION , SELECTOR_Y_BUFFER, (self.view.frame.size.width - 2 * X_BUFFER)/CGFloat(viewControllerArray.count), SELECTOR_HEIGHT))

    selectionBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    selectionBar.alpha = 0.8
    navigationView.addSubview(selectionBar)
    }
```

Now we can use the scroll view's **scrollViewDidScroll** delegate in order to make the selection bar view slides towards the selected menu. Each time this delegate is called whenever the page view controller is scrolled, we change the frame of selected bar view every moment.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let xFromCenter : CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width-scrollView.contentOffset.x;

    let xCoors : CGFloat = X_BUFFER + selectionBar.frame.size.width * CGFloat(currentPageIndex) - X_OFFSET
    _ = selectionBar.frame

    if(CGFloat(xCoors)-xFromCenter / CGFloat(viewControllerArray.count) > self.view.frame.size.width - selectionBar.frame.width)
    {
        selectionBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - selectionBar.frame.width, selectionBar.frame.origin.y, selectionBar.frame.size.width, selectionBar.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if(CGFloat(xCoors)-xFromCenter / CGFloat(viewControllerArray.count) < 0)
    {
        selectionBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, selectionBar.frame.origin.y, selectionBar.frame.size.width, selectionBar.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
       selectionBar.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(xCoors)-xFromCenter/CGFloat(viewControllerArray.count), selectionBar.frame.origin.y, selectionBar.frame.size.width, selectionBar.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

For more details please see the sample link below.

https://github.com/RajanMaheshwari/PageViewController

Comment: @KevinGuan I have updated the answer and included the essential parts from the link for which the author of the question was asking. Thanks

Comment: Wow, looks great now ;)